# I'd Like to login with other social networking websites like Tumblr

Tags: feature-request, login, social-networking

When I first made my account I had to use yahoo. But I prefer to login to external things like this with a social networking websites instead of my email account. Not everybody uses Facebook. Some of us like Tumblr and things.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like someone already came up with a way to do that:

http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/813934427/tumblr-url-google-profiles-openid

Does that work for you?